# proper usage code section for super. and Log.d

Tags: android, android-logcat

Where to use `super.onStop` or `super.onPause` and `Log.d` at the ideal location in android coding? I am a beginner with little knowledge in Java!!

```
  super.onPause();
  Log.d(msg, "The onPause() event");
```

Comment: Ideally, the constructors of the super class should be called in the respective overridden methods. For eg. `super.onPause()` in `onPause()` method. `Log` is used for debugging purpose. So there's no ideal position to call it.

Answer (score 2):

`super` represents the base class of current class. If written in your activity like `MainActivity` then it would represent the class from which `MainActivity` is inherited.

You can call any of the base class method using `super` keyword if that is not a private method.

Ideally we call `super.anyMethod()` inside the overriden method in your class. So `super.onStop()` should be called in the `onStop()` method and `super.onPause()` should be called in the `onPause()` method of your activity.

There are various log levels in Android. See [this for more information](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) on that.

`Log.d` method should be called when you want to see any debug output in the logcat window and it has no fixed or recommended place to be called. It can be called anywhere you want to print a log.

Log printing is always optional and shouldn't be printed in release build.